# PHP Execution after accidental connection termination

Tags: php, httprequest

If, during a normal HTTP request, the connection is accidentally terminated as a PHP script is being executed, will the script terminate too or will it continue executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can decide whether or not you want a client disconnect to cause your script to be aborted.
>
> The default behaviour is however for your script to be aborted when the remote client disconnects.

[PHP Connection handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php)